# What exactly is Function.prototype()? Is it a suitable default value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, web

In NodeJS and the browser, if you call `Function.prototype()`, it returns `undefined`.

Calling `Function.prototype.toString()` returns `"function () { [native code] }"`.

Is this an empty function? Is it suitable to use in place of `() => {}` for defaults (e.g. default prop for React component)?

Comment: [*Function.prototype*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object) is a function object, it's defined in ECMA-262.  When called, it's specified to return *undefined*. It's purpose is to act as the object that function instances inherit their methods from. `Function.prototype` is 12 more characters than `()=>{}`.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, this is what I was looking for.